# Problem while taking input using cin after detaching that thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, cin, infinite

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int input(int time, int *ptr)
{
    int sec = 0, flag = 0;
    thread t1([&]()
            {
                cin >> *ptr;
                sec = 0;
                flag = 1;
                t1.detach();
            });
    thread t2([&]()
            {
                while (flag == 0)
                {
                    if (sec == time)
                    {
                        if (t1.joinable())
                        {
                            t1.detach();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    Sleep(1000);
                    sec++;
                }
            });
    t2.join();
    return flag;
}
int start(int time, int *ptr)
{
    return input(time, ptr);
}
int main()
{
    int arr[10], flag2 = 1, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " element: ";
        flag2 = start(2, arr + i);
        if (flag2 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    cout << endl
        << "Array elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << *(arr + i) << " ";
    }
    int temp;
    cout << "\nEnter temporary value: ";

    cin >> temp;
    cout << "Here is what you gave as input: " << temp;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter 1 element: 5
Enter 2 element: 2
Enter 3 element: 6
Enter 4 element: 8
Enter 5 element:

Array elements: 5 2 6 8
Enter temporary value: 7
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  No such process
```

**Expected output:**

```
Enter 1 element: 5
Enter 2 element: 2
Enter 3 element: 6
Enter 4 element: 8
Enter 5 element:

Array elements: 5 2 6 8
Enter temporary value: 7
Here is what you gave as input: 7
```

**Code overview:**
Above code takes array input from user until user wants to stop, like I want to take infinite input from user, for linked list/stack/queue, I know that array has fixed size, but my problem is not with taking infinite input, that works fine, I used two thread one thread (timer t2) for counting seconds (in this case 2 seconds) and another (input t1) to take input from user. When user finished giving input he just need to wait for 2 seconds and thread t2 will detach thread t1, and now here comes the problem.

**Problem:**
Everything is right till line 59, but then when I try to take input for 'temp' an exception occurs, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what():  No such process. As I said before about my code, I am taking pointer from user and storing value at that address. But, when user stopped giving input and thread t2 detached t1, then code resumes, no problem till here but input of cin inside thread t1 remain incomplete, it requires an input, hence when I give input for 'temp' it takes it for my previous input inside thread t1 which was detached by thread t2 without taking input, I think, since that thread is no longer attached to main thread, this exception comes.

Is there any solution available for this?
I tried a lot but failed, please review my code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The way `detatch` is being used here is very incorrect and indicates you misunderstood what it does or how it work. Can you please elaborate on what you think it does? Then, it may be easier to help clear up your misunderstanding.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to implement a timeout for `std::cin`. This is not possible using portable code, it may be possible using platform specific functions.

Comment: You have no memory fences for any of your shared (across threads) variables.  Therefore you have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Yes François, my plan was same to create a timeout for cin, after timeout reached it's final value cin must stop taking input and code continues. But, seems like it is not possible, cin waits to take input, but if I want to take input from user for only once then it'll work, cause I tested, I can use cout after this function is over but I can't take any input again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you should use atomic shared variables across threads.
The `std::cin` is blocking operation. In your code two seconds later doing detach for thread1. But `std::cin` still waiting for input...
The console window can `std::cin` or `std::cout` but not both at the same time so you need to change algorithm to avoid this problem.

Comment: Ok, so I can't simply detach thread without taking cin input, I thought that thread will get destroyed along with that cin will no longer wait for input and will get closed by itself, because of I'm creating function, since after function completes it's work and returns, it gets destroyed so I thought it'll work but cin waits for input and that's why exception occured. Also, you are right I can't take input or print output at the same time, I tried that but no luck.